# Copy common fields between structs of different types

Tags: go

I have two structs, whose types are as follows:

```golang
type UserStruct struct {
    UserID      string            `bson:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    Address     string            `bson:"address" json:"address"`
    Email       string            `bson:"email" json:"email"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time         `bson:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
    PhoneNumber string            `bson:"phone_number" json:"phone_number"`
    PanCard     string            `bson:"pancard" json:"pancard"`
    Details     map[string]string `json:"details"`
}

type SecretsStruct struct {
    UserID      string    `r:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    Secrets     []string  `r:"secrets" json:secrets`
    Address     string    `r:"address" json:"address"`
    Email       string    `r:"email"json:"email"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `r:"created_at"json:"created_at"`
    PhoneNumber string    `r:"phone_number" json:"phone_number"`
    PanCard     string    `r:"pancard" json:"pancard"`
}
```

I already have an instance of `UserStruct`. I want to copy the fields common to both structs from `UserStruct` to a new instance of `SecretStruct`, without using reflection.

Comment: So just copy the relevant fields.

Comment: Is there any other way, these structs are going to get bigger, i was looking for a smart solution. In python, if i want to create a copy of a list on some condition, I dont do element wise operation, just saying.

Comment: Go isn't Python, just saying. Maybe you should clarify why you don't want to do it by hand (it'll only be a couple lines of code, if your structs are so massive that it isn't a couple lines of code then you have a different problem) or why you don't want to use reflection.

Comment: lesson learnt, I will not compare any languages from now on. Just out of curiosity, what kind of problems i would face when i would have massive structs.

Comment: "what kind of problems i would face when i would have massive structs" None. At least none from copying.

Comment: @muistooshort "Go isn't Python" Quote of the day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Go is a statically typed language** (and is not Python). If you want to copy fields between the structs, you must either **cause code to be supplied at compile time** which knows how to do this, or **use the `reflect` library** to perform the operation at runtime.

---

Note that I said "cause code to be supplied at compile time" because you *don't have to explicitly write that code*. You could use code generation to produce the copy code from the struct definitions, or from a higher-level definition (e.g. XML) which generates both the struct definition and the copying code.

However, **good Go programmers prefer clear code over clever solutions**. If this is a single localized requirement, writing a code generator to avoid "boilerplate" code is almost certainly overkill; its implementation will take longer than the code to copy the structs, and the associated complexity will introduce a risk of more bugs. Similarly, `reflect`-based solutions are complicated, *not* clear, and  only recommended in cases where you require a generic or extensible solution, and where this cannot be fulfilled at compile time.

I recommend simply write the copying code, and add appropriate comments to the `struct` definitions and copy methods to ensure future maintainers are aware of their obligation to maintain the copy methods.

---

### Example

```golang
// Define your types - bodies elided for brevity

// NOTE TO MAINTAINERS: if editing the fields in these structs, ensure
// the methods defined in source file <filename>.go are updated to
// ensure common fields are copied between structs on instantiation.
type UserStruct struct { ... }
type SecretStruct struct { ... }

// NewSecretStructFromUserStruct populates and returns a SecretStruct
// from the elements common to the two types. This method must be
// updated if the set of fields common to both structs is changed in
// future.
func NewSecretStructFromUserStruct(us *UserStruct) *SecretStruct {
    // You should take care to deep copy where necessary,
    // e.g. for any maps shared between the structs (not
    // currently the case).
    ss := new(SecretStruct)
    ss.UserID = us.UserID
    ss.Address = us.Address
    ss.Email = us.Email
    ss.CreatedAt = us.CreatedAt
    ss.PhoneNumber = us.PhoneNumber
    ss.PanCard = us.PanCard
    return ss
}

// You may also consider this function to be better suited as
// a receiver method on UserStruct.
```